# org.springframework.boot Configuration with name 'runtime' not found

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, gradle

When trying to run my program using gradle bootRun, the error shows that

Failed to apply plugin 'org.springframework.boot'
Configuration with name 'runtime' not found

The following is my `build.gradle`

```
 buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.5.3.RELEASE")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'war'
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'application'

jar {
    baseName = 'blockchain-demo'
    version = '0.0.1'
}

war {
    baseName = 'blockchain-demo'
    version = '0.0.1'
}

application {
    mainClass = 'web.Application'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

dependencies {
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools")
    testCompile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test")
    testCompile("junit:junit")
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I assume you're using Gradle 7. In Gradle 7, the configurations `compile`, `testCompile`, `runtime` and `testRuntime` have been removed in favor of `implementation`, `testImplementation`, `runtimeOnly` and `testRuntimeOnly`. That's why Gradle issues

> Failed to apply plugin 'org.springframework.boot' Configuration with name 'runtime' not found

To fix the issue, you should use the Gradle version that is supported by the Spring Boot Gradle Plugin version you're using (1.5.3, according to the snippet provided). The [system requirements](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.x/reference/htmlsingle/#getting-started-system-requirements) lists Gradle version 2 and 3 as requirement for Spring Boot 1.5.3. Everything thereafter is not supported.

Comment: As a note to others, I was able to port a Spring Boot 1.5.21 application from Gradle 4.10.3 to Gradle 6.8.3. Without changing any other thing, I wasn't able to upgrade further to Gradle 7.3.3 though for which I got the above mentionned error message: `Failed to apply plugin 'org.springframework.boot' Configuration with name 'runtime' not found`.

Answer (score 3):

Spring Boot 2.5.0 supports Gradle 6.8, 6.9, or 7.x

See here for a good reference on Gradle 7 configurations: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.5.0/gradle-plugin/reference/htmlsingle/

This will get you off the ground:

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.5.0'
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'

dependencies {
    implementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
    implementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa')
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
```